# Building a desktop admin panel for react native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am building a react native app with firebase auth and cloud storage, and I was just wondering if it is possible to make a dashboard for desktops to administrate the users/app? And if it does, how do I do this? Is it in the same build, or do I have to build a new "app" for adminpanel/dashboard?

This is my first time building the adminpanel/backend xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to build web apps with React Native, I wouldn't recommend it. The Layout of a desktop is just way too different from phones to build React Native Apps including web without constantly using `Platform.OS`. In your question, you even mention that you wan't the dashboard to just be available on the desktop but not on the Phone (which makes sense in my opinion). Since you seem to know a bit about React Native, it should be an easy thing for you to build the Dashboard as a different Application with React for the web only.